# Use Fetch POST to save (persist) data to a JSON file on server

Tags: javascript, json, post, fetch, persistent-storage

I want to save data to a static JSON file sitting on my server using a Fetch POST request.

Is this possible to do? If so any tips or advice would be appreciated

My Javascript code to try save data to my JSON file.

```
fetch('link-data.json', {    
method:'POST',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
            'Content-type':'application/json'
        },
        body:JSON.stringify({
            id:3,
            title:"website_title",
            url:"www.example.com",
            description:"Hi_there_im_a_description"
             })
        })
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((data) => console.log(data))
```

My JSON file I want to save the data to.

```
[
{
  "id": 0,
  "title": "Twitter. It's what's happening.",
  "url": "https://twitter.com/?lang=en",
  "description": "From breaking news and entertainment to sports and politics, get the full story with all the live commentary."
},
{
  "id": 1,
  "title": "Netflix - Watch TV Shows Online, Watch Movies Online",
  "url": "https://www.netflix.com/",
    "description": "Watch Netflix movies & TV shows online or stream right to your smart TV, game console, PC, Mac, mobile, tablet and more."
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "title": "Facebook - Log In or Sign Up",
      "url": "https://www.facebook.com/",
      "description": "Create an account or log into Facebook. Connect with friends, family and other people you know. Share photos and videos, send messages and get updates."
    }
]
```

Comment: Where is the server code?

Comment: @CaduDeCastroAlves Currently I don't have any :O

Comment: You can't write a file on the server via JavaScript. You should use a server-side language like PHP or NodeJS to do so. What server-side language do you already know?

Comment: It is possible, but you're trying to send the JSON to `www.example.com`. You need to set up your own endpoint for this to work.

Comment: @CaduDeCastroAlves I know PHP

Comment: example.com should just be saved as string @BrandonDyer

Comment: Oh, you're right. I assumed the body of your request was the JSON you wanted to send. My point still stands though. You need to create an endpoint to hit.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. If you are using Node.Js, there is a simple way to achieve that. Let's say you are making the POST request to website.com/saveFile. Then the code would look something like this:

```
const url = require('url')
const http = require('http')
const fs = require('fs')

const server = http.createServer((req, res)=>{
    switch(url.parse(req.url).pathname){
        case '/saveFile':
            let body = ''

            //saving post data into variable body
            req.on('data', chunk=>{
                 body+= chunk.toString()
            })
            req.on('end', ()=>{
                //reading json file
                fs.readFile(__dirname+'/link-data.json', (err, data)=>{
                    if (err) throw err
                    dataJson = JSON.parse(data) //object with your link-data.json file
                    postData = JSON.parse(body) //postData is the variable containing your data coming from the client.
                    dataJson.push(postData)//adds the data into the json file.

                    //Update file
                    fs.writeFile(__dirname+'/link-data.json', JSON.stringify(dataJson), (err)=>{
                      if(err) console.log(err)
                      res.end()
                    })
                })
            })
    }
})

server.listen(5000, ()=>{
    console.log('Server listening at port 5000!')
})
```

What this do is to open the JSON file using the File System (FS) Node.Js internal module, parsing it to an Javascript object and adding the data to the array. Then the file is updated (using the function fs.writeFile()).

You could also send a JSON response to signal everything went as planned:

`res.end(JSON.stringify({"status": "success"}))`

Comment: Thanks for the node.js reply but I need to use PHP to do this.
Also where would this server side code sit? Is it its own file which I target when i make my Fetch POST request?

Comment: In this case the PHP code would be in the root folder and the POST request would be made to it. You could apply the same concept to the PHP code using something like

`$jsonString = file_get_contents('jsonFile.json')` and `$data = json_decode($jsonString, true); ` to access and update the JSON file. Look around online and you will certainly find how to do this.

Comment: I have been trying to write this in PHP but am getting errors 'uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input'. Here is my PHP:
<?php
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *',
    "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" : true);
    
    $jsonString = file_get_contents('link-data.json')
    $json_arr = json_decode($jsonString, true);

    if(!$json_arr) {
        $json_arr = array();
    }

    $json_arr[] = $_POST;

    $jsonString_done = json_encode($json_arr);
    file_put_contents('link-data.json', $jsonString_done);
?>